# IIS6 returning 403 for all requests containing "Translate:f" header

Tags: iis-6, webdav

I'm a developer working on a custom WebDav integration which works locally but fails on the live servers. I get a 403 Forbidden error for any requests that contain the header "Translate:f" and I cannot find where or why this might be blocked. The live server is using IIS6 which is different to my development machine (IIS7).

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Adam.

UPDATE - this was resolved by adding "Script source access"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by adding "Script source access"